# Python beautifulsoup - getting input value / TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to find the formkey but getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

On [this webpage](https://wellgosh.com/customer/account/create/).

need to find the value.
What I am searching for can be found 
at view-source:https://wellgosh.com/customer/account/create/ and control+f name="form_key" value=

```
formkey_acc = soup.find('input', {'name': 'form_key'})['value']
```

```
s = requests.session()

def c_acc():
    acc = s.get('https://wellgosh.com/customer/account/create/')
    soup = bs(acc.text, 'html.parser')
    formkey_acc = soup.find('input', {'name': 'form_key'})['value']
    print(formkey_acc)
```

```
formkey_acc = soup.find('input', {'name': 'form_key'})['value']
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

They are 403'ing on the default user-agent of requests...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def c_acc(s):
    acc = s.get(
        'https://wellgosh.com/customer/account/create/',
        headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36"}
    )
    soup = bs(acc.text, 'html.parser')
    formkey_acc = soup.find('input', {'name': 'form_key'}).get('value')
    print(formkey_acc)

s = requests.session()
c_acc(s)
```